# call a function when navigating to next or previous record in MS access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have a split form and when the user navigates through the records in the datasheet using the standard arrow on the bottom I want to be able to call a VBA function I wrote to populate a listbox in the top part of the form. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Current` event.

> The Current event occurs when the focus moves to a record, making it the current record, or when the form is refreshed or requeried.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I tried so many of those event none of them worked.